# Rewriting/simplifying $\int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1+a} \exp(b*x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to write:

$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1+a} \exp(b*x) dx$$

in a more elegant way? (without the integral)

I tried wolframalpha (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%281-x%29%5E%28a-1%29%20exp%28-b*x%29%20%2C%20x%3D0..1)), but it didn't provide a solution..

Comment: Is $a∈\Bbb N$? Or $a\geq 0$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor $a\geq 0$

Answer (score 4):

We consider $b \neq0$ (this case would be trivial). For issues of convergence we also assume the $Re{(a)}>0$ (real part of a is positive).

$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1+a} \exp(bx) dx$$

Now apply two substitutions:

1. $u=1-x$ and $\mathrm{du} = -\mathrm{dx}$:

$$\int_1^0 u^{-1+a} \exp[b(1-u)] (-1)\mathrm{du}$$
$$e^b\int_0^1 u^{-1+a} \exp(-bu)\mathrm{du}$$

2. $v=bu$ and $\mathrm{dv} = b\mathrm{du}$: 
   $$e^b\int_0^b (\frac{v}{b})^{-1+a} \exp(-v)\frac{\mathrm{dv}}{b}$$
   $$\frac{e^b}{b^a}\int_0^b v^{a-1} \exp(-v)\mathrm{dv}=\frac{e^b}{b^a}\gamma(a,b)$$

Where $\gamma(a,b)$ is the incomplete gamma function. In general, there is no closed expression for the last integral using only elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: In order to simplify, use property of definite integration:  $\color{blue}{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx}$

$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{-1+\alpha}e^{bx}dx=\int_{0}^{1}(1-(1-x))^{-1+\alpha}e^{b(1-x)}dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1+\alpha}e^{b(1-x)}dx$$
$$=e^{b}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1+\alpha}e^{-bx}dx$$

Comment: So you can't ''remove'' the integral?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^{-1+a} \exp(b y) \ dy = 
(1-x)^{-1+a} \int_0^1  \exp(b y) \ dy = \begin{cases}(1-x)^{-1+a} \frac{e^b-1}{b} & b≠ 0 \\ (1-x)^{-1+a} &b=0 \end{cases}$$